# DNS. Для чего нужны записи типа NS?

Tags: dns, ns

Зачем нужны DNS записи типа NS?
Ведь они возвращают только **имя** авторитетного DNS сервера.
Потом ведь всё равно придётся делать ещё один запрос, чтобы по этому имени узнать реальный адрес.

Зачем эта лишняя операция? Почему сразу не запросить IP нужного DNS сервера?

В книге сказано только что:

> Такой тип записи используется, чтобы
>   направлять DNS-запросы дальше по цепочке.

Но до меня что-то не доходит.

Comment: Ассоциация: https://serverfault.com/q/764937/412506

Comment: tl;dr: чтобы не навязывать конкретный протокол, вроде IPv4; помимо общих причин "зачем вообще нужны доменные имена".

Comment: простой ответ в виде двух вопросов: 1. а почему ns-запись должна дублировать a-записть (т.е, ipv4-адрес), а не, например, aaaa-запись (т.е., ipv6-адрес)? 2. зачем содержимое этой записи вообще должно что-либо дублировать?

Answer (score 4):

`NS` запись указывает, куда стучаться за подробной информацией по домену.

> Зачем эта лишняя операция, почему сразу не запросить IP нужного DNS
>   сервера?

Ну вот пишите вы приложение, вам нужно послать запрос на свой сервер. У вас выбор, посылать сразу по IP или по доменному имени (тогда будет использоваться NS запись).

Вы куда-то выложили своё приложение. Но вот незадача, у вас упал сервер, вы подняли новый, там другой IP, что делать будете? Пересобирать приложение?

Если бы вы использовали доменное имя, то вы бы просто поменяли `A` запись, а тот, кто ответственен за всё это дело (тот, кто у вас в `NS` записи) всё настроит и при обращению по имени домена теперь новый IP будет выдаваться. Ну да, там есть промежуток времени, пока DNS `A` запись ещё не сменилась и пользователям будет резолвится старый IP, но это всяко лучше, чем пересобирать приложение. Для решения этих проблем есть всякие балансеры и т.п, но это уже совсем другая задача.

Comment: ну, вообще-то на суть вопроса тут ответа как раз и нет. краткая же суть такова: «почему бы не хранить в ns-записи ipv4-адрес вместо имени?». ответ при этом, конечно, очевиден: «[не одним же ipv4 жив интернет](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2549)». (более серьёзная [ссылка с перечислением альтернатив](https://www.quora.com/Is-there-an-alternative-to-the-TCP-IP-model-that-does-not-utilize-the-Internet-Protocol-IPv4-6))

Comment: @alexanderbarakin да я сам уже вижу, что ответил не совсем на то, что автор спрашивал =/